# Prove the following sum is convergent when n tends to infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove the following sum is convergent :

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}-n}{n}$$

Comment: Please don't shout.  What makes you think it is convergent?

Comment: That's not convergent.

Answer (score 4):

$$\frac{\sqrt{n(n+1)}-n}{n} = \frac{n(n+1)-n^2}{n\left(\sqrt{n(n+1)}+n\right)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}+n}.$$

Of course, the $n$-th term goes to $0$ as $n$ goes to $+\infty$. Anyway, notice that:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n(n+1)}+n} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2}+n} = \frac{1}{2n}.$$

Since it is well known that $$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n}$$ does not converge, then also your series do not converge.

Answer (score 3):

$\dfrac{\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}-n}n=\dfrac{(\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}-n)(\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}+n)}{n(\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}+n)}=\dfrac{n(n+1)-n^2}{n(\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}+n)}=\dfrac{n}{n(\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}+n)}=\dfrac 1{(\sqrt{n}\sqrt{n+1}+n)}\sim \dfrac 1{2n}$

So the series has positive terms which are equivalent to these of the harmonic series which is a divergent series, so it is divergent as well.

Comment: Well, I guess I'm typing slower than the Candyman...

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sqrt{n^2+n}-n}{n}=\frac{\left(\sqrt{n^2+n}-n\right) \left(\sqrt{n^2+n}+n\right)}{n \left(\sqrt{n^2+n}+n\right)}=\frac{n^2-n^2+n}{n \left(\sqrt{n^2+n}+n\right)}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+n}+n}$$
$$=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{n}+1\right) n^2}+n}=\frac{1}{n\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+1} +n}=\frac{1}{n \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+1}+1\right)}$$
This last expression is asymptotically equivalent$^*$ to $\dfrac{1}{2n}$ which proves that the given series is divergent, because $$\frac {\sqrt{n^2+n}-n}{n}\sim \frac {1}{2n}$$
and the equivalent series diverges, like the harmonic series.

$(*)$
Indeed $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\frac{\frac{1}{n \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+1}+1\right)}}{\frac{1}{2n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\,\frac{2n}{n \left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{n}+1}+1\right)}=1$$

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

$a_n:= \dfrac{\sqrt{n(n+1)} -n}{n} = $

$\dfrac{\sqrt{n+1} -√n}{√n} =$

$\dfrac{1}{√n(\sqrt{n+1} +√n)} >$

$\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{n+1}\sqrt{n+1}}=$

$\dfrac{1}{2(n+1)} =:b_n.$

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}b_i < \sum _{i=1}^{n}a_i,$ i.e.

divergent.